# How to scrape Cyrillic text using Scrape-it Note.js

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, utf-8, scrape, cyrillic

I need to scrape text in Cyrillic. But I get ������ ������ ��������� instead of "Четыре тысячи четыреста".

I use this code:

```js
    var data = {
       Name:{
            selector:maindir + "h1.moviename-big",
            // convert:function(x){
            //     return x.toString('utf-8');
            // }
    }
    }

    function callback(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            page = scrapeIt.scrapeHTML(body,data);
            inf.List.push(page);
            jsonfile.writeFile('List.json', inf, { spaces: 2}, function (err) {
                console.error(err || 'success Write in Json')
            });
        }
    }
```